# Flutter: How to correctly apply ImageFilter to the current layer?

Tags: flutter, canvas, imagefilter

I am trying to apply a sequence of `ImageFilter`s to the currently drawn `Canvas` layer.

```dart
canvas.drawCircle(...)
canvas.drawCircle(...)

// TODO Apply ImageFilter 1: Blur
// TODO Apply ImageFilter 2: Blur again
```

Is there an easy way to do that? I'm likely missing some simple method, but I could not find anything...

---

##### Things I have tried:

I know that I can specify the combined `ImageFilter` in `Paint`, but this does not work - I want to apply them in sequence *after* all shapes are drawn, rather to each shape separately.

[`saveLayer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/saveLayer.html) seems to be the closest to achieve what I need, but according to docs it only applies `ColorFilter`. They also say it is a bit inefficient.

```dart
saveLayer(null, Paint()..colorFilter = filter2)
saveLayer(null, Paint()..colorFilter = filter1)
..
canvas.draw
canvas.draw
...
restore()
restore()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this will apply the effect to each drawn shape separately. I found something in the meantime PaintingContext.addLayer could be the solution, trying it out...

Comment: Yep, thanks, I managed to do that with Layers and the render box.

Answer (score 1):

For the future reference, I was able to achieve the desired effect by using the `RenderBox` (this can be used for example from `LeafRenderObjectWidget`).

The `RenderBox` has the paint method:

```dart
@override
void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    context.pushLayer(
      ColorFilterLayer(colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(...)),
      (PaintingContext context2, Offset offset2) => 
          context2.pushLayer(
            ImageFilterLayer(imageFilter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(...)),
            (PaintingContext context3, Offset offset3) =>
                simulation.draw(context3.canvas),
            offset2),
      offset);
```

Not that the `simulation.draw(context3.canvas)` will draw in a canvas that is followed by the blur `ImageFilter` and then by the `ColorFilter`. Any number of `Layers` can be added, the syntax is a bit painful though. It can be simplified with some effort if needed:

```dart
/// Returns the painter with the given layer applied.
PaintingContextCallback withLayer(
    ContainerLayer layer, PaintingContextCallback painter) {
  return (PaintingContext context, Offset offset) =>
      context.pushLayer(layer, painter, offset);
}

...
final List<ContainerLayer> layers = [...];
var painter = ...
for (final layer in layers) {
  painter = withLayer(layer, painter);
}
painter(context, offset);
```

Comment: Thanks already much cleaner! In my case I was applying a variable number of filter so I ended up with a simple helper function, updated the answer.

Comment: Your paste has a timeout so could not include it as the alternative suggestion :( I think yours could be better in some cases.